# Configure multiple web application over ssl including apps without using wildcard certs

Tags: sharepoint-addin, ssl

Let's admit it wildcard certs are evil (unless you can convince me otherwise, highly doubtful). for the past few months I've been thinking of ways to set up my SharePoint 2013 apps environment without using wildcard certs. I already have apps working over http and also already have multiple web applications running on the same port 443. Due to architecture of apps I'm having a hard finding a solution, there's gotta be one. Thank you for your suggestions and answers; anything will head.

Answer (score 1):

Managing **multiple web application** over **SSL** is not an easy talk for developers.

**Wildcard SSL** - It allows developer to manage and secure unlimited number of sub-domains or apps (if App domain is a sub-domain) with single certificate.

The other solution is **Multi Domain SSL**

**Multi Domain SSL** will allow developer to manage and secure multiple domains/apps over SSL with single certificate.

Comment: Thank you Laura, however due to the security risk of wildcard certs, I'm trying to stay away from them. As you know they can be worse than self-signed certificates in a production environment. Multi-domain SSL unfortunately will not work in these situation since in SharePoint 2013 apps we don't don't know what the sub-domain will be until after the app is created. Also, it changes every time the app is installed on a site collection.

Comment: Well, If you are choosing Multi domain SSL, you can add, edit or delete your domains.

But Each time you add, edit you need to reissue the certificate from your certificate authority.

If you are purchasing Comodo Multi domain SSL, it will let you to add up to 2005 multiple domains names with single certificate (To add an extra domain you only need to purchase SAN cert)... So if your Domains are not more then 2005 it will be the best option.